# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 12288 bytes for committing reserved memory

Tags: java, memory, jvm, native, heap-memory

We are running tomcat 9 with JVM 8 version. We have set min-heap as 2GB, Max is 7GB. But we are very often seen Native memory allocation (mmap) failed error. Heap Conf Looks like:

`"-Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Xms2048M -Xmx7168M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M"`

I can see before failure there is enough heap then why it failing.
Our System vm.max_map_count

```
sysctl vm.max_map_count
vm.max_map_count = 65530
```

free -m total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:     52187       19653         452          40       32082       32012
Swap:    4095          80        4015 .

I observed OS  vm.max_map also keep on increasing , usually on linux default size is around 65k. yesterday it was 8k(when tomcat restarted) now it increased to 25k

```
pmap 46012|wc -l
33410

 
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 12288 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (os_linux.cpp:2627), pid=51706, tid=0x00007f403bbbf700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_102-b14) (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.102-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f48d9131800):  JavaThread "CBONLINE-DBAdapter-DB-Pool connection closer" daemon [_thread_new, id=68713, stack(0x00007f403babf000,0x00007f403bbc0000)]

Stack: [0x00007f403babf000,0x00007f403bbc0000],  sp=0x00007f403bbbe9a0,  free space=1022k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0xac52aa]  VMError::report_and_die()+0x2ba
V  [libjvm.so+0x4fc29b]  report_vm_out_of_memory(char const*, int, unsigned long, VMErrorType, char const*)+0x8b
V  [libjvm.so+0x922603]  os::Linux::commit_memory_impl(char*, unsigned long, bool)+0x103
V  [libjvm.so+0x9226cc]  os::pd_commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, bool)+0xc
V  [libjvm.so+0x91c17a]  os::commit_memory(char*, unsigned long, bool)+0x2a
V  [libjvm.so+0x92089f]  os::pd_create_stack_guard_pages(char*, unsigned long)+0x7f
V  [libjvm.so+0xa6a55e]  JavaThread::create_stack_guard_pages()+0x5e
V  [libjvm.so+0xa73d44]  JavaThread::run()+0x34
V  [libjvm.so+0x9249c8]  java_start(Thread*)+0x108
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x7ea5]  start_thread+0xc5


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007f48d9132800 JavaThread "DBAdapter-DB-Pool connection adder" daemon [_thread_new, id=68714, stack(0x00007f4035156000,0x00007f4035257000)]
=>0x00007f48d9131800 JavaThread "DBAdapter-DB-Pool connection closer" daemon [_thread_new, id=68713, stack(0x00007f403babf000,0x00007f403bbc0000)]
  0x00007f4914add000 JavaThread "AS40


OS:Oracle Linux Server release 7.9

uname:Linux 3.10.0-1160.2.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 22 09:10:02 PDT 2020 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.17 NPTL 2.17 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 160274, NOFILE 65535, AS infinity
load average:4.07 5.27 5.04

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:       41053988 kB
MemFree:          353240 kB
MemAvailable:   18211824 kB
Buffers:               0 kB
Cached:         17371124 kB
SwapCached:        30176 kB
Active:         27419984 kB
Inactive:        9387136 kB
Active(anon):   17764840 kB
Inactive(anon):  1767940 kB
Active(file):    9655144 kB
Inactive(file):  7619196 kB
Unevictable:       12380 kB
Mlocked:           12380 kB
SwapTotal:       4194300 kB
SwapFree:        3862524 kB
Dirty:             18944 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      19420940 kB
Mapped:            76264 kB
Shmem:             85784 kB
Slab:            1544296 kB
SReclaimable:    1019240 kB
SUnreclaim:       525056 kB
KernelStack:      757520 kB
PageTables:       138316 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    24721292 kB
Committed_AS:   65627724 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      296108 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359310332 kB
Percpu:            28672 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:  12632064 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      341824 kB
DirectMap2M:     8046592 kB
DirectMap1G:    35651584 kB
```

What is the idle solution to resolve this problem?

Comment: How much RAM do you have on the system? What is the exact error message? Any other processes consuming significant portions of memory? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48592602/native-memory-allocation-mmap-failed-to-map may help too

Comment: free -m total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          52187       19653         452          40       32082       32012
Swap:          4095          80        4015 .

Comment: Do you have a complete crash report from the time the JVM process failed? (something like here: https://serverfault.com/questions/962275/java-crash-due-to-native-memory-allocation-map-failure-despite-n). 
It seems you have plenty of memory on that machine but would be interesting to get those numbers (`free -m` and `pmap <pid> | wc -l` ) just before the JVM crashes.

And I suppose you've seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815309/java-outofmemory-exception-mmap-error-on-loading-zip-file

Comment: pmap 46012|wc -l = 33,345 we have three servers all having same counts.            free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          52187       21196         345          47       30645       30461
Swap:          4095          82        4013

Comment: @Juraj I updated all detail in question section, attached excat error also memory info when JVM crashed. my only concern why pmap size kept increasing, why object are not deallocated from the map. It seems this is causing native memory leak.

Comment: It seems your crash file is quite incomplete - full details usually contain much more info including the list of all the threads, etc. But I don't think I can give you a satisfying answer. Based on the stacktrace, I'd say it's failing when creating a new Thread (`create_stack_guard_pages` in the stacktrace). Maybe you're creating a _lot_ of threads? However, It seems you have enough "available" memory (18G) at the point of the crash. If @apangin (he's a true JVM expert) finds time to look at this he might give you a better answer.